# Cannot fetch location with cordova-geolocation-plugin (timout error)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have been trying to get the location of the user with the cordova-geolocation-plugin, but there seems to be a very weird problem. It works and I'm able to get the coordinates in some phones, while in others it doesn't work and shows a timeout error. Also I don't find any similar pattern in the phones which it works and in the ones which it doesn't. It works in some nougat phones and doesn't in other. Same goes with other versions and models. There is just no pattern.
I have followed up similar questions about this but still not able to get it working properly.

```
$scope.getCurrentLocation = function () {
            var onSuccess = function (position) {
                console.log('Latitude: ' + position.coords.latitude + '\n' +
                      'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude + '\n' +
                      'Accuracy: ' + position.coords.accuracy + '\n');
            };

            function onHighAerror(error) {
                console.log('code: ' + error.code + '\n' +
                      'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
                         //Low accuracy fallback
                         navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onLowAerror, {enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 60000});

            }

             function onLowAerror(error) {
                console.log('code: ' + error.code + '\n' +
                      'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
            }

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onHighAerror, {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 60000});
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try following way. Hope this will useful to you. More detail could be found on [this link](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/geolocation/)

```js
$scope.getCurrentLocation = function() {
   $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

     var posOptions = {
       enableHighAccuracy: true,
       timeout: 50000,
       maximumAge: 0
     };

     $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions).then(function(position) {
       var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
       var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

     }, function(err) {
       console.log(err);
     });
   });
 }
```

Also Check following permissions are added into the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NETWORK_ACCESS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

Comment: Same problem, works on some phones and not on others

Comment: Can you give an idea about in witch devices it did work and it didn't work

Comment: Does not work in Nexus 5, Lg L90, Xiaomi Redmi 1S.
Works in Yu Yuphoria, Xperia Sp(CM Nougat), Xiaomi Mi 4

Comment: android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE is important in your case

Comment: Nope, still no, added all the permissions.